# select elements in df pandas according to another column value in df

Tags: python, pandas

I have my df as following:

In [2]: df
Out[2]:

```
    A  B  C
0  b1  1  0
1  b2  1  0
2  b1  3  1
3  b1  2  1
4  b2  2  1
5  b2  4  1
```

I want to use a pandas command to just select elements according the column B:

In [2]: df_new
Out[2]:

```
   A  B  C
0  b1  1  0
1  b2  1  0
3  b1  2  1
4  b2  2  1
```

Cheers,
Behzad.

Comment: Use `df = df[df['B'].isin([1,2])]`

Comment: Hi jezrael, but what I have in 'B' is not always 1 and 2. I want to say select all elements in 'A' if they have same 'B' when their 'C' is the same.

Comment: Can you check solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) for boolean mask by 2 columns and `keep=False` for return all dupes and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.duplicated(['B', 'C'], keep=False)]
print (df)
    A  B  C
0  b1  1  0
1  b2  1  0
3  b1  2  1
4  b2  2  1
```